# Knex how to build an array POSTGRES query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

i try to query some data with knex.js using this:

```js
let query = knex
  .select(
    'project.custom_answer.id',
    'project.custom_answer.content',
    'project.custom_answer.is_private',
    knex.raw(
      'CASE ' +
        'WHEN proposal.custom_question.id IS NULL THEN NULL ' +
        'ELSE json_build_object(' +
        "'id', proposal.custom_question.id," +
        "'content', proposal.custom_question.content," +
        "'is_mandatory', proposal.custom_question.is_mandatory," +
        "'is_private', proposal.custom_question.is_private," +
        "'has_media', proposal.custom_question.has_media," +
        "'category', proposal.custom_question.category," +
        "'type', proposal.custom_question.type," +
        "'proposal'," +
        'CASE ' +
        'WHEN proposal.proposal.id IS NULL THEN  NULL ' +
        'ELSE json_build_object(' +
        "'id', proposal.proposal.id," +
        "'is_private', proposal.proposal.is_private," +
        "'slug', proposal.proposal.slug," +
        "'name', proposal.proposal.name" +
        ')' +
        'END' +
        ') ' +
        'END as custom_question'
    )
  )
  .select([
    knex.raw(
      'CASE ' +
        'WHEN proposal.custom_answer.id IS NULL THEN  NULL ' +
        'ELSE ARRAY_AGG(json_build_object(' +
        "'id', proposal.custom_answer.id," +
        "'content', proposal.custom_answer.content" +
        '))' +
        'END as custom_answer'
    ),
  ])
  .modify(querybuildUtils.mediaBuilder, 'project.custom_answer.media_id')
  .join(
    'proposal.custom_question',
    'proposal.custom_question.id',
    'project.custom_answer.custom_question_id'
  )
  .leftJoin(
    'proposal.custom_answer',
    'proposal.custom_answer.custom_question_id',
    'proposal.custom_question.id'
  )
  .join('proposal.proposal', 'proposal.proposal.id', 'proposal.custom_question.proposal_id')
  // .modify(joinUserAsObject,"project.answer.member_id")
  .from('project.custom_answer')
  .limit(100)
  .whereIn('project.custom_answer.id', arrayId)
  // .where("project.custom_answer.is_private", "false")
  .orderBy('project.custom_answer.created_at', 'desc')
  .groupBy(
    'project.custom_answer.id',
    'proposal.custom_question.id',
    'proposal.custom_answer.id',
    'proposal.proposal.id'
  );
```

I want to get my custom_question with the first knex.raw and create an array for my custom_answer with the second knex.raw.
My issue here is that create an array for each custom_question AND custom_answer so now my data look like:

```
custom_answers: [
{
  content: "",
  custom_answer: [{id: 59, content: "A1"}]
  custom_question: {id: 236, content: "Q1" ....}
  ...
},
{
  content: "",
  custom_answer: [{id: 60, content: "A2"}]
  custom_question: {id: 236, content: "Q1" ....}
  ...
},
]
```

And that what i want:

```
custom_answers: [
{
  content: "",
  custom_answer: [
    {id: 59, content: "A1"},
    {id: 60, content: "A2"},
  ]
  custom_question: {id: 236, content: "Q1" ....}
  ...
}
]
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a `join` but a nested subquery aggregating to an array.

Comment: @Bergi like add `.options({nestTables: true})` after my `leftJoin` ?

Comment: I don't know knex and I couldn't find proper documentation on what that option does, but from a cursory glance it looks right.

Comment: Thank you for your help but same issue with the option.